# Time subtraction in C

Tags: c

I would like to subtract current_time with previously_saved_time and check if it's bigger then wait_time. wait time should be an int. Can someone give me a simple example? In other words:

```
if ((current_time - previously_saved_time) > wait_time) {
    do something;
}
```

Comment: [man time](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time) with [man difftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/difftime) might be a reasonable starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is exactly what you need, other than replacing `do something` with some actual code.

For example, this program waits three seconds:

```
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    time_t base = time (0);
    time_t now = base;
    while (now - base < 3)
        now = time (0);
    return 0;
}
```

It simply loops in the `while` statement until the difference between the base time and the current time is three or more (there are almost certainly better ways to wait for `N` seconds, this is just meant to illustrate the calculation).

Comment: Note that the C standard thinks you should use `difftime()` to calculate the difference between two `time_t` values such as those returned by `time()`.  POSIX takes a simpler view of life (at least w.r.t `time_t`; let's not discuss all the sub-second timing mechanisms) and the direct subtraction works.

Comment: I used those calculations since it wasn't clear that the values _were_ `time_t` types. If they are then `difftime` is probably the way to go since the encoding of a `time_t` is not actually mandated by the standard.

Comment: The C standard doesn't tell whether `time_t` is `signed` or `unsigned`. It only says `...clock_t and time_t which are arithmetic types capable of representing times...` and `The range and precision of times representable in clock_t and time_t are implementation-defined.` So, I guess, subtracting `time_t`'s from one another can have issues if the type is unsigned.

Comment: Yes, if you subtracted a later time from an earlier one. That doesn't appear to be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

check out time.h you will find the needed function to get current system time.

Or the Wiki Page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_time